# My page won't let me use method after changing system date

Tags: jsp

I have a page which similar to booking system, in my page I import java class which contains a method to detect wether a booking is expired, validated or used.
For the validated and used I have no problem, but for the expired one (not expired after being used, but expired for being not validated after amount of time) I meet this problem:

I book a room to use in 11-06-2013, I don't validate it. And then change system date to 15-06-2013, I tried to refresh the web page, but it doesn't update the book entry as 'expired'.  But if I run the java class it updated the book entry. Does JSP doesn't recognize the change in my system date?

Info: My expiration is when a booking is more than a day not validated.

**Edit: Here's some code**

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
String code, status, count, standard, deluxe, superiors, superiord;
Date dateNow, dateIn, dateOut;
dateNow = cal.getTime();

rs = db.view("select * from booking");
try {
    while (rs.next()) {
        code = rs.getString("code");
        standard = rs.getString("standard");
        deluxe = rs.getString("deluxe");
        superiors = rs.getString("superiors");
        superiord = rs.getString("superiord");
        status = rs.getString("status");
        count = rs.getString("isCount");

        dateIn = dateFormat.parse(rs.getString("datein").toString());
        dateOut = dateFormat.parse(rs.getString("dateout").toString());

        if (dateNow.equals(dateIn)) {  //This is after being validated
            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Paid")) {
                if (count.equalsIgnoreCase("False")) {
                    db.insert("update room set standard=standard-" + standard + ", deluxe=deluxe-" + deluxe + ", superiors=superiors-" + superiors + ", superiord=superiord-" + superiord + "");
                    db.insert("update booking set status='Being used', isCount='True' where code='" + code + "'");
                }
            }
        } else if (dateNow.after(dateIn)) {  //This is expired one
            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Waiting")) {
                db.insert("delete from booking where code='" + code + "'");
            }
        } else if (dateNow.after(dateOut)) {  //This is after being used or finished
            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Dipakai")) {
                db.insert("update kamar set standard=standard+" + standard + ", deluxe=deluxe+" + deluxe + ", superiors=superiors+" + superiors + ", superiord=superiord+" + superiord);
                db.insert("update pesan set status='Selesai' where code='" + code + "'");
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

My page cannot read the second if (expired) after I change my system date to the future.

Comment: show some code please

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your code and knowing what your doing I can't really know for sure but I will say that changing the system time as a test is a bad idea.

For one it will screw up JSP compilation and compilation in general.

What you should do is go write some [Unit Tests](http://junit.org/) and make it so that the current time is a passed into a method. In your Unit Tests you pass in a hard coded time instead of `Calendar.getInstance()`.